# How to boot computer after shutdown during updates?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, boot, power-supply, freeze

I shut my computer down while doing updates in Windows Vista.  Now it will not turn on, and I get no response when I hit the power button.

Do I have to take it to a professional?

Comment: try a repair install using the original installation media?

Comment: When you say 'no response', you mean nothing, not even a flicker or a whirr?  That's not a software problem.

Comment: You might consider posting you Make and full model number of your laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a silly question, but you do have the power lead connected, right?

If you are on power, or after you plug in, press and hold the power button for up to 10 seconds, release, and then press it again. If the laptop comes on, gently keep pressing F8 while it starts until you get to the Advanced Boot Options screen and select Safe Mode. If you get this far, restart and try booting normally and finish the updates. If you don't get that far, try finishing the updates in Safe Mode. If it does boot up normally after this, I'd probably run a diagnostics check, just for peace of mind.

Comment: Nice description of getting it going again. +1 for you.